Having issues getting Conda to initialize
I installed Anaconda on my D drive and when I go to initialize Conda I get this, it’s looking for the files that are on the D: drive. How can I switch it up so it’ll initialize? Thanks for any help, apologies if this isn’t the right place to post this, I’m very new at working with this.
Tried moving the files in the screen shot to the directory and I still got the same message

you have not posted any error message of what is happening

Sorry, I guess it won't let me post screenshots, here's the gist of it:                                               WARNING: Cannot install xonsh wrapper without a python interpreter in prefix: C:\Users\jtdus\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI56882
needs sudo    C:\Users\jtdus\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI56882\Scripts\conda.exe
needs sudo    C:\Users\jtdus\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI56882\Scripts\conda-env.exe         And it goes on like this for a few more files.
